# Has default behavior for settings variables for hidden components in install4j 6 changed?

Tags: install4j

We have a form with several components. One of the them is a checkbox for which we've set visibility script to `false`. In effect, this component is never shown. 
In older versions of `install4j`, that would still set the associated variable value to Boolean `FALSE`. However in latest `install4j (6.0.1)`, the property is no longer getting set causing our installer to fail with `NullPointerException` when we try to access this property. Can you please confirm if that is indeed the case and if you plan to change it back to old behavior?

Answer (score 0):

That change was intentional. It is described in the blog post about [migrating to install4j 6](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2014/11/migrating-to-install4j-6.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20ejtblog%20%28ej-technologies%20new%20%26%20noteworthy%29).

The relevant section is:

> Invisible form components are no longer validated. A validation error
>   would leave the user with no clue what to do, so this was really a
>   mistake in previous versions. However, bound installer variables are
>   set during the validation phase and that will no longer happen for
>   invisible components. If you rely on the installer variables to be
>   defined, you should predefine them in the "Installer variables"
>   section of the installer or custom installer application.